# Filtering and rearranging model/content in Ember Controllers

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-model

Let's say I have a JSON array of data, something like:

```
[ {"name":"parijat","age":28},
  {"name":"paul","age":28},
  {"name":"steven","age"27},
...
]
```

that is part of my model, and this model is setup like this:

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return App.User.FIXTURES ; // defined above
   }
});

I want to get the unique ages from this JSON array and display them in my template, so I reference the computed properties article and read up a little on how to enumerate Ember Enumerables, to eventually get this:

```
    App.UserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
         ages:function(){
              var data = this.get('content'); 
              var ages = data.filter(function(item){
                       return item.age;
             });

        }.property('content');
});
```

Now the above piece of code for controller is not correct but the problem is that it doesn't even go into data.filter() method if I add a console.log statements inside. IMO, it should typically be console logging as many times as there exist a App.Users.FIXTURE. I tried using property('content.@each') which did not work either. Nor did changing **this.get('content')** to **this.get('content.@each')** or **this.get('content.@each').toArray()** {spat an error}.

Not sure what to do here or what I am completely missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter is used for reducing the number of items, not for mapping.

You can use data.mapBy('age') to get an array of your ages:

```
ages:function(){
  return this.get('content').mapBy('age');
}.property('content.@each')
```

or in your handlebars function you can just use the each helper:

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  {{item.age}}
{{/each}}
```